# Issue while reading JSON file with updated values in web application

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, multithreading, web-applications

I am developing a dashboard and facing some issues while displaying values on it.

My Java code writes JSON messages in a file (within WebContent) and is being accessed in my JS script to display values on dashboard.

The problem is that even thought the message gets written to the file, values don't update on dashboard. As soon as I open the JSON file, proper values starts to populate on the web page. I can't see any errors too.

Below is the code which is writing to Sample.json file. And I am making an Ajax call from below URL to get the content in JS.

```
try(FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/Users/<PATH>/Workspace/Project/WebContent/Sample.json")){
    file.write(res);
    file.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'Sample.json',
    success: function(res) {

        $('#id').text(res.measurements[0].value);
    },
    error: function(e) {

        console.log(e);
    }
    });
    });
```

Please help me understand why is this happening and what should be the approach to solve it.

Comment: In ajax req success function you need to add result to html. Something Like $(body).append(res): or display in log to test

Comment: your success function does nothing - and you see nothing happening ... can you see the correlation

Comment: Sorry, I was doing it my JS code but hadn't added that here. The problem persists with this too. Do please check the  edited the snippet.